# How to use a sub-query to pick out corresponding value for another minimum

Tags: sql, db2, dataset

I'm trying to find a name of a Community Area that corresponds to the minimum safety score in another column.
Current code is

```
select COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME, SAFETY_SCORE from CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS
where (COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME,SAFETY_SCORE) in (select COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME, min(SAFETY_SCORE) 
from CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS group by COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME)
```

[resulting table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqt11.jpg)

What I want is a table that has COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME defined as WASHINGTON PARK and SAFETY SCORE defined as 1.

| COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME | SAFETY_SCORE |
| --- | --- |
| WASHINGTON PARK | 1 |

Dataset is taken from here: https://data.cityofchicago.org/Education/Chicago-Public-Schools-Progress-Report-Cards-2011-/9xs2-f89t

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
    select COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME, min(SAFETY_SCORE) as min_score
    from CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS 
    where SAFETY_SCORE in (select min(SAFETY_SCORE) from CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS)
    group by COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME
```

Comment: It did! Thanks very much :)

Comment: @LouisF.Meikle . . . You should use `=` not `in` for this.